# In Gnu screen terminal emulator, when quiting from vim does not clear the screen automatically

Tags: linux, vim

During using Gnu screen(screen manager with VT100/ANSI terminal emulation), I fall across a trouble that when I quit from the vim, screen will not clear the screen automatically.Althrough I can clear the screen manually(<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd>),but I really want the screen clear the sreen automatically.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the terminal to look the same it did before you called vim that is, put the following line in your .screeenrc:

```
altscreen on
```

then when you start a new screen it should work.